# spring annotation server loading time it showing class not found exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

server loading time it showing this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception
>   is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class
>   [com.vcs.model.Student] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.vcs.model.Student

Comment: Add more relevant code, especially for the controller that caused this error.

Comment: also add this class com.vcs.model.Student